# Can you have option object arguments be as members in class constructor?

Tags: typescript

In Typescript, each constructor arguments with an accessor are recognized as class members.

```
class Test {
  constructor(private arg1, private arg2) { }
                      ~~~~          ~~~~ recognized as members
}
```

And you can use "options object".

```
class Test2 {
  constructor({arg1, arg2}: {arg1: string, arg2: number}) { }
}
```

or

```
class Test3 {
  constructor(options: {arg1: string, arg2: number}) { }
}
```

Then, are there any ways to define members based on each arguments in constructors with options object?

Like:

```
class Test4 {
  constructor({private arg1, private arg2}: {arg1: string, arg2: number}) { }
}
```

Do I have to define class members independently?

```
class Test4 {
  private arg1: string
  private arg2: number
  constructor({arg1, arg2}: {arg1: string, arg2: number}) {
    this.arg1 = arg1
    this.arg2 = arg2
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Stated below is the best you can do with TypeScript.

```
class Test1 {
    constructor(private arg1: string) {}
}

class Test2 {
    constructor(private options: { arg1: string; arg2: number }) {}
}
```

I think what you are trying to do is deconstruct `options` and set their properties in the class. You cannot deconstruct the properties of `options` directly in the parameters of the constructor. So this one line in the constructor might help

```
class Test2 {
    constructor(private options: { arg1: string; arg2: number }) {
        Object.assign(this, options)
    }
}
```

But the issue with this solution is that you don't get type annotations for `this.arg1` and `this.arg2` even though they exist in the class. So it's best if you stick to assigning each property separately

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have already come up with the former two examples so it means there are no perfect solutions that I'd like. I'm glad to know it from your answer. I appreciate it.